# Separation through the intersection of prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $K$ be a field and $K[x, y]$ the polynomial ring . I want to prove:

$(x-a,(y-b) (y+b)) = (x-a, y-b)\cap (x-a,y+b). $

I know to prove '$\subset$', but I don not have ideal about the other direction...

Comment: Use the Taylor expansion. Then you have the isomorphism $K[x,y]/(x)\simeq K[y]$ and the latter is a principal ideal domain.

Comment: I can't see it ...

Comment: Is it possible that this fact be false for an arbitrary closed algebraic field?

Answer (score 0):

$x\mapsto x+a, y\mapsto y+b$ defines an isomorphism of rings $K[x,y] \simeq K[x,y]$, the inverse being $x\mapsto x-a, y \mapsto y-b$. This is the *algebraic* Taylor expansion.
Replace $2b$ by $b$ and we see that the ideals are mapped to $(x,y(y+b)), (x,y), (x,y+b)$. All of these contain $(x)$ and so does $(x,y)\cap (x,y+b)$. Since quotient by some ideal preserves inclusion among those containing it, it suffices to show the equality in $K[x,y]/(x)\simeq K[y]$, i.e. $(y(y+b))=(y)\cap (y+b)$. The inclusion $\subset$ is easy as you know. We can use the fact $K[y]$ is a PID, in particular, an unique factorization domain to show the equivalence $a \in (y)\cap (y+b)\iff a$ divisible by $y$ and $y+b$, for $a\in K[y]$.
If $b\neq 0$(originally $2b\neq 0$), $y, y+b$ are distinct irreducible elements, so the equivalence extends to $a\in (y(y+b))$. In the case $b=0$, $y\in (y)\cap (y)$ but $y\notin (y^2)$ so they are not the same.